# Visual C++2013 Go To Definition goes to 2010 MFC sources and it should not

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, migration

I recently upgraded my Visual C++ solutions and projects from 2010 to 2013. And I am correcting the things that impede them from compiling.

On lines like

```
m_Impl.GetMenuBar()->RestoreOriginalstate();
```

I receive the error

```
error C2039: 'RestoreOriginalstate' : is not a member of 'CMFCMenuBar'
```

If I *Go to Definition* of `GetMenuBar`, 2013 has that function and goes to the right place, the file

```
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxframeimpl.h
```

But if I *Go To Definition* of `RestoreOriginalstate`, it goes to

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxmenubar.h
```

which is absolutely wrong, because 2013 has not this function and this header file belongs to the 2010 installation.

How can I stop *Go To Definition* to go erroneously to the 2010 sources?

Comment: Check your project settings and verify that you don't have hardcoded paths to the Visual Studio 2010 directories.

Comment: In VS2013, VC++ Directories editing in Tools -> Options is deprecated. I would check how those settings were migrated to the project's property sheet.